# Creating an executable jar executing a war file with embedded jetty

Tags: java, jsp, jersey, jetty

I'm new to jetty. I need to make a executable jar which embed jetty as well as a war file. On double clicking this jar, the Server should start and deploy my project war file.This is the code that i have written.I'm not using maven.

```
public class TestJetty {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            int port = 9008;

            Server server = new Server(port);
            final String WEBAPPDIR = "war/SampleApp.war";
            final URL warUrl = TestJetty.class.getClassLoader().getResource(WEBAPPDIR);
                System.out.println(warUrl.toExternalForm());
                WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext(warUrl.toExternalForm(),"/SampleApp"); 
            server.setHandler(webapp);
            server.start();
            server.join();
        }
}
```

In the hosting project, I have created a folder war and placed the SampleApp. It works when I execute this file from eclipse. the SampleApp executes while deployed from eclipse(running as a java application). But the same does not work when I make it as an executable jar(which I export it from eclipse). In fact, when i execute the executable jar, the following happens.
1. The server starts up.
2. When the path is specified,the path will be displayed in form of a hyperlink. On Clicking this link, the war file gets downloaded into my local system.
**I'm using the following jars.**
servlet-api-3.0.jar
jetty-jsp-2.1-7.5.4.v20111024.jar
jsp-api-2.1-6.1.5.jar
jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
com.sun.el-2.2.0.v.201108011116.jar
org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.7.1.jar
jsp-2.1-6.1.5.jar
jetty-all-8.1.9v20130131.jar

Please help me how to resolve this. I need to execute my war file from the executable jar.

Comment: You didn't mention what is exactly happening when your run from jar. Any errors ?

Comment: No, it does not show any errors, but the web page generates a hyper link to download the war file, insted of executing the same.

Comment: This may help http://www.javalobby.org/articles/tomcat2go/

Comment: My boss is looking for a solution deployed in jetty.

Comment: It could be some minor issue, but i'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: Would you please be more specific regarding the problem?
What is your expectation and what happens and what does not? I don't understand "When the path is specified,the path will be displayed in form of a hyperlink. On Clicking this link, the war file gets downloaded into my local system." Which path? Where is the hyperlink shown? how can you click that?

Comment: In simpler terms.. I need to create an executable jar file which has an embedded jetty server and a war file in it. On Double Click of this executable jar,the war file should be deployed.

Comment: Presently, I am not able to do so.The server runs, but the war file present is not getting extracted.